# Searching a jqGrid from Jquery UI Dialog causes search string from request to be an empty string

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

My requirement needs me to display a jqGrid in an Jquery UI popup dialog.

**Behaviour noticed :**
I am able to perform paging, sorting, searching but when I call the same in a Jquery UI dialog it does not search. It only does paging and sorting.

**My Research :**
I noticed when I called the same JgGrid without it being displayed in the Jquery UI dialog it does searching, paging and sorting.

**HTML Code below:**

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var curRowNum = 0;
        var curPressedButton = '';
        var curPressedNum = 0;

        $(function () {

            $("#test").click(function () {
                $("#dialog-form-lookup-site").dialog('open');             
            })

            $("#tblSiteLookup").jqGrid({

                url: 'Handlers/SitesHandler.ashx?l=sa',
                datatype: "json",
                height: 200,
                width: 600,
                mtype: 'post',
                loadonce : true,
                colNames: ['Guid', 'Company', 'Customer Site', 'Annual Consumption (kWh)'],
                                    ],
                colModel: [
                            { name: 'Guid', index: 'Guid', search: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq']} },
                //{ name: 'price', index: 'price', width: 60, search: true, stype: 'text', searchoptions: { dataInit: datePick, attr: { title: 'Select Date'}} },
                            {name: 'Company', index: 'Company', width: 70, sortable: true, editable: false, searchtype: "number", search: true, stype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq']} },
                            { name: 'CustomerSite', index: 'CustomerSite', width: 70, sortable: true, editable: false, search: true, stype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq']} },
                            { name: 'AnnualConsumption', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: false }
                          ],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#pager11',
                sortname: 'Company',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",             
                caption: "Site"
            });

            $("#tblSiteLookup").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager11', { search: true, edit: false, add: false, del: false, searchtext: "search" });

            $("#dialog-form-lookup-site").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 450,
                width: 700,
                modal: true,
                dialogClass: 'no-close',
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function () {

                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function () {
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="HtmlForm" runat="server">
     <div>    
    <input id="test" type="button" value="Test Sites List" />
    </div>
    <div id="dialog-form-lookup-site" title="Lookup Site"> 
        <table id="tblSiteLookup" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        </table>
        <div id="pager11" style="width:500px">
        </div>
    </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code on the server side in the SitesHandler.ashx:**

```
public class SitesHandler : IHttpHandler , IRequiresSessionState
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle the request
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {            
            HttpResponse response = context.Response;


           string siteLists = GetSitesList();
           response.Write(siteLists);
       }
 }
```

**Question** :

> How do I call this from the above JQuery UI popup so that the search
>   works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading the jQuery library from 1.11.1 to 1.9.1 fixed the issue. Looks like the new Jquery library may not be compatible to the search feature of the JgGrid.

Code belows shows commented library code and library code in use which fixed this issue, hope this helps just in case you all bump into this issue:

```
  <%--<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>


        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```